# pyodbc 64b cursor.execute()

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am learning python and I have a database connection issue.

Using :
 - pyodbc3.0.9 
 - pydev 4 througt eclipse Luna Release 2 (4.4.2) 
 - python 3.4.3 64b (conda v3.11.0 tagged as 'dirty')
 - Windows 8.1 (64b)

When I run this

```
import pyodbc

__connection = pyodbc.connect(DSN='PostgreSQL35W')
print("Step1")
__cursor = __connection.cursor()
print("Step2")
__cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
print("Step3")
__rows = __cursor.fetchall()
print("Step4")
for row in __rows:
    print("Step5 (loop)")
    print("row:",row)
```

The console display result :

```
Step1    
Step2
```

Then, still running indefinitely without any warning or error or timeout (in fact the table "table" does not exist, but at this point I just want to establish the connection)...

I can't even figure out with certitude what the problem is, any ideas ?

Comment: Resolved by using psycopg2 instead of pyodbc.
If someone have an idea on the problem with pyodbc module, I am still interested.